# why my function doesn't execute after clicking dynamically created button

Tags: asp.net, event-handling

here is my scenarioton  : if !page.Ispostback i fill a dropdown with data from database! 
Also in the page there is a butron and onclick it gets one id from database and crates one panel IN WHIH THERE IS DYNAMICALLY CREATED BUTTON. The PROBLEM IS WHEN I CLICK THIS DYNAMICALLY CREATED BUTTON _ JUST NOTHING HAPPENS AND I CANT EXPLAIN WHY.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ddlLanguages.DataSource = this.catRep.GetAllAvailableLanguages();
                ddlLanguages.DataBind();
            }

            //IEnumerable<CatgoriesLanguages> allcategories = this.catRep.GetAllCategoriesByID(1)

        }



        protected void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inseredID = this.catRep.AddCategory();

            Label mylab = new Label();
            mylab.Text = "Yeeee" + inseredID;
            Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(mylab);

            Panel myFieldSet = new Panel();
            myFieldSet.GroupingText= "Add New Category";
            Label lblTitle = new Label();
            lblTitle.Text="Title: ";
            myFieldSet.Controls.Add(lblTitle);
            TextBox txbTitle = new TextBox();
            txbTitle.ID = "txbTitle";
            myFieldSet.Controls.Add(txbTitle);
            myFieldSet.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

            Label lblShrtDescrpt = new Label();
            lblShrtDescrpt.Text = "Short Description: ";
            myFieldSet.Controls.Add(lblShrtDescrpt);
            TextBox txbShrtDescrpt = new TextBox();
            txbShrtDescrpt.ID = "txbShrtDescrpt";
            myFieldSet.Controls.Add(txbShrtDescrpt);
            myFieldSet.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
            Label lblDescrpt = new Label();
            lblDescrpt.Text = "Description: ";
            myFieldSet.Controls.Add(lblDescrpt);
            TextBox txbDescrpt = new TextBox();
            txbDescrpt.ID = "txbDescrpt";
            myFieldSet.Controls.Add(txbDescrpt);
            Button btnAddcategorieslanguage = new Button();
            btnAddcategorieslanguage.Click += new EventHandler(btnAddcategorieslanguage_Click);
            myFieldSet.Controls.Add(btnAddcategorieslanguage);
            Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(myFieldSet);



        }
        public void btnAddcategorieslanguage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            TextBox txbTitle = (TextBox)FindControl("txbTitle");
            TextBox txbShrtDescrpt = (TextBox)FindControl("txbShrtDescrpt");
            TextBox txbDescrpt = (TextBox)FindControl("txbDescrpt");



            this.catRep.AddCategoriesLanguages(11, 2, "malee", "tariiiiii", "liliiii");

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create all dynamically added controls in page Init or page load event too.
Something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    if(ThereIsDynamicControl())
    {
    //You can set some session or viewState in the btnAddNew_Click to determine whether you need to add dynamic controls again here or not.
    }
         if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ddlLanguages.DataSource = this.catRep.GetAllAvailableLanguages();
                ddlLanguages.DataBind();
            }
     //IEnumerable<CatgoriesLanguages> allcategories = this.catRep.GetAllCategoriesByID(1);
            }
```

Comment: So i Actually have to recreate the controls which I create in BtnAddNew

Comment: Yes.You need to do that.

Comment: Thanks very much it worked after recreating the dynamic controls